# Trigonometric Substitution

Tags: calculus

I am having some difficulty with a homework question and would like to ask for some help. The question that I do not understand reads: "Use the substitution $x=6\sin(t)$ to evaluate the integral $\sqrt{36-x^2}dx.$" I understand I need to substitute the $x^2$ with $(6sin(t))^2$, so that the integral is  $\sqrt{36-6\sin(t)^2}dx$ but I am not sure what to do from there.

Comment: Don't forget that you also have to express $dx$ as a function of $dt$.

Answer (score 2):

If you let $x=6\sin(t)$, then $x^2$ becomes $36\sin^2(t)$ **not** $6\sin^2(t)$.  From here you will get $\sqrt{36-36\sin^2(t)}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $dx=6\cos tdt$ and so
$$\int \sqrt{36-36\sin^2t}\cdot 6\cos tdt
\\=36\int \cos^2tdt$$ then use the double angle rule. To go back to $x$ draw a right angle triangle with sides $x,6$ and angle $t$ satisfies  $x=6\sin t$

Answer (score 0):

Take the integral:
 integral sqrt(36-x^2) dx
For the integrand sqrt(36-x^2), substitute x = 6 sin(u) and  dx = 6 cos(u)  du.
 Then sqrt(36-x^2) = sqrt(36-36 sin^2(u)) = 6 cos(u) and u = sin^(-1)(x/6):
  =  36 integral cos^2(u) du
Write cos^2(u) as 1/2 cos(2 u)+1/2:
  =  36 integral (1/2 cos(2 u)+1/2) du
Integrate the sum term by term and factor out constants:
  =  18 integral 1 du+18 integral cos(2 u) du
For the integrand cos(2 u), substitute s = 2 u and  ds = 2  du:
  =  9 integral cos(s) ds+18 integral 1 du
The integral of cos(s) is sin(s):
  =  9 sin(s)+18 integral 1 du
The integral of 1 is u:
  =  9 sin(s)+18 u+constant
Substitute back for s = 2 u:
  =  18 u+9 sin(2 u)+constant
Apply the double angle formula sin(2 u) = 2 cos(u) sin(u):
  =  18 u+18 sin(u) cos(u)+constant
Express cos(u) in terms of sin(u) using cos^2(u) = 1-sin^2(u):
  =  18 u+18 sin(u) sqrt(1-sin^2(u))+constant
Substitute back for u = sin^(-1)(x/6):
Answer:   
 |   =  1/2 sqrt(36-x^2) x+18 sin^(-1)(x/6)+constant